# latest update to 16.04 broke my wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

I have a Dell laptop with a BroadCom BCM4312 wireless chipset that was working fine until I updated to the latest 16.04 kernel (4.4.0-43) & libs.  My dmesg and lspci are visible via the pastebin link below, it appears that it knows/sees my broadcom driver but there is also some messaging about a tainted kernel which I don't fully know what it's complaining about.  Bottom line is the latest kernel update killed me.  I tried a 'service network-manager restart' and 'service network restart' trying to kick the kernel drivers but no soap. I need some guidance on how to debug this and get this backup ASAP.
Thanks

http://pastebin.com/Ay5U0c8G

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the wrong driver. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

After it completes, reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: That didn't do it, still down.

Comment: Let's have a look at some additional diagnostics. Please edit your question to add the result of: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep b43` Thanks.

Comment: rfkill:0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: I plugged a USB wireless adapter in, so it shows phy; 0 (my broken Broadcom port and this other adaptor) that's why there are two showing in the rfkill output.

Comment: paste bin of dmesg for b43 device: http://pastebin.com/LKy8Qcih

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the NIC in the laptop and still had the same issue.  I then installed a NIC in the adjoining mini-PCIe slot and attached the antennas intended for the WWAN card this slot is labeled for.  This second NIC worked/connects to the network.  The only thing I can think of is that somehow the original mini-PCIe slot has a problem that doesn't preclude it communicating with the system, but does preclude it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to this chart, your wireless card is supported by both the B43 driver and the WL proprietary broadcom driver.

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Supported_devices

If you are not having luck with b43, i'd suggest reinstalling bcmwl kernel source (after purging it).

**Here is how to switch drivers (copied from linuxwireless.org):**

Switching between drivers

If you have few drivers installed, system may auto-load different driver than the one you wanted to use. Manual (un)loading drivers can be done with modprobe tool.

To unload all known drivers (you can pick only one command, if you know which driver is in use) perform:

```
Toggle line numbers

   1 modprobe -r b43 bcma
   2 modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
   3 modprobe -r wl
```

To load specific driver use one of the following commands:

```
Toggle line numbers

   1 modprobe b43
   2 modprobe brcmsmac
   3 modprobe wl
```

It is possible to prevent system from auto-loading some drivers by blacklisting them. This can be done with the following command:

```
Toggle line numbers

   1 echo "blacklist drivername" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

If you plan to use wl, you should blacklist b43 and brcmsmac as well as bcma. Unfortunately wl does not use bcma bus driver, so this additional step is required.